# Angular Material input type number auto format 0001 to 1

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a input type number code of

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="timeTaken" type="number"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

It do allow to accept 0001, do it have any possible way to make 0001 auto format become 1 when user key in and click other place (when unfocused this number field)

So it can somehow look like windows calculator, on windows calculator no matter how many 0 you type. It just show a single 0 then next press 5 it show 5

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `onfocusout` event handler to your `input` element as follows:

```
<input ... type="number" onfocusout="this.value = Number(this.value)"/>
```